# $n$ children throw respectively one ball at $m$ buckets at the same time, how many buckets can we expect to be empty?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Assume that $n$ children throw respectively one ball at $m$ buckets at the same time. The children throw so well that everyone hits a bucket. Determine the expected amount of empty buckets.

First, we need a random variable $X$ that counts the number of the empty buckets. We define

$$X := X_1 + X_2 + \ ... \ X_m,$$

with $X_k = 1$ if the $k$-th bucket is empty (and $0$ otherwise).

The probability for one arbitrary bucket being empty can be calculated the following way:

Since there are $m$ buckets, there is a chance of ${m-1 \over m}$ that one arbitrary child does *not* hit one specific bucket. Since there are $n$ children throwing the balls, there is a chance of $({m-1 \over m})^n$ that one specific bucket remains empty after every ball has been thrown. $X_k$ is obviously Bernoulli-distributed, so $E(X_k) = ({m-1 \over m})^n$

Using the linearity of the expected value, I receive

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^m \bigg({m-1 \over m}\bigg)^n = m\bigg({m-1 \over m}\bigg)^n$$

Using some examples, this seems to make sense. Say, we have $2$ children throwing the balls at $100$ buckets, we would receive $E(X) = 98,01$, which means that a little bit more than $98$ buckets should be empty, which makes sense considering the fact that both children could hit the same bucket, although it is quite unlikely.

Is this solution correct? Furthermore, is there another, maybe more "combinatorial-like"-way to go about this? This question was asked in our Discrete class, and although we did some probability theory there, I feel like there might be another approach to this problem.

Comment: Linearity of expectation is the way to go. But when I see a sum of the form $\sum_{k=1}^m a$, I can't usually resist writing it as $ma$.

Comment: @Andreas: Could you elaborate? Why should the second child hit the same bucket or another one with a probability of $0.5$? The probability of "hitting the same bucket or another one" should be $1$, actually, since there is no other option for the result.

Comment: You're right. We should have: The second child hits a bucket independently of the first child. Considering your example of 100 buckets and two children throwing. The first child hits some bucket. With probability 0.01, the second child hits the same bucket. So the expectation value of empty buckets is 0.01*99 + 0.99* 98 =  98.01

Comment: @Andreas: Well, the question mentions that the children throw the balls "at the same time", which is supposed to imply that they hit the buckets independently from each other, I guess. But I admit that it's written a little bit confusing.